# Importing ArrayFire Causes Hang When Complete

Tags: python, anaconda, arrayfire

I'm not sure if this is an Anaconda, Arrayfire, or Windows issue, but importing Arrayfire into a script seems to be causing the script to hang when complete.

I'm using Anaconda as my python environment on Windows 7

```
    Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 15 2017, 03:34:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

If I don't import arrayfire, the everything works as expected from the python prompt. (I'm using the Anaconda Prompt)

```
>>> print "Test"
Test
>>> exit()

C:\Users\nanoPhD>
```

If arrayfire is imported, arrayfire it works fine, but the console will hang, indefinitely, upon exiting.  It is hard to demonstrate that the console is frozen, but below is an example of where it freezes. The only remedy is to exit the console.  No errors or exception thrown.

```
Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 15 2017, 03:34:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import arrayfire as af
>>> af.info()
ArrayFire v3.5.0 (CUDA, 64-bit Windows, build 05999f3)
Platform: CUDA Toolkit 8, Driver: CUDA Driver Version: 8000
[0] Quadro K3100M, 4096 MB, CUDA Compute 3.0
>>> exit()
```

I've tried reinstalling Anaconda and Arrayfire.  I've also tried it on multiple virtual environments with no success.   I'm out of ideas and hoping y'all may be able to help.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what the actual problem ended up being, but my IT department forced me upgrade my OS and therefore had to reinstall everything. That seemed to fix it.